# Create comparison-of-means table with multiple variables by multiple groups comparing to total mean

Tags: stata

I'm looking for a way to create a comparison-of-means (t-test) table from the output of a tabstat command. Basically, I want to know if the mean of each group is statistically significantly different from the mean for the variable overall.

I have 75 variables across 15 groups for a total of 1125 t-tests, so doing them one at a time is out of the question.

I could always write a loop for the tests, but I was wondering if there was a command similar to tabstat that would make the table for me. Google has been unhelpful thus far, even though it seems like a fairly logical place to go from a tabstat output.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can offer an example as to how you plan to combine `tabstat` and t-test. I am not sure if a t-test helps you compare group means to the grand mean. Assuming sufficient sample size, I'd rather go about this analysis with a regression with 14 dummy variable. `estout` can then fit 4 or 5 dependent variables in a table.

Comment: @Aspen , The goal is to analyze the results of a k-means cluster. I have 75 variables that I used to group the data into 15 clusters. Now I want to look at what the driving factors are in each group (i.e. what variables in each group make that group stand out from the others).

A regression would be unhelpful, since the only independent variable I have is an unordered categorical variable which I'm looking to cluster into similar groups, not try to predict.

Comment: I see. So just for clarification: it sounds to me you are looking for a one sample t-test that, for example, first **su v1** and then **ttest v1=`r(mean)' if group==1**. Is that right?

Comment: Yes - that is exactly it. I need a way to do that 1125 times (a foreach loop, for example) and grab the t-stat and p-value for each test and put them all in a table. The latter step is the part I'm not sure on. I was actually able to do it in Excel using the TDIST() formula, so there's that. It would be nice to get it all done in Stata, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be packages that better serve you, but here's an example that I just put together. It's assuming you are using the one sample t-test because I can't see another way to do it with a t-test. This block of code returns a matrix with three things: the difference from the grand mean, the t value, and the p value.

Feel free to adapt the code as you see fit. Actually it'd just take a few more steps to make it into an ado file.

```
sysuse auto,clear
loca varlist mpg weight length price                // put varlist here
loca grpvar foreign                                 // put grouping variable here
loca n_var=wordcount("`varlist'")
qui tab `grpvar'
loca n_grp=`r(r)'

mat T=J(`n_var'*3,`n_grp',.)                        // (# of vars*3, # of groups,.)

**colnames
    loca cnames=""
    su `grpvar', meanonly
    forval i=`r(min)'/`r(max)'  {                   // assuming consecutive sequence
        loca cnames="`cnames'"+" "+"`i'"
    }
    mat colnames T=`cnames'                         // values of grouping variable

**rownames
    loca rnames=""
    forval  i=1/`n_var' {
        loca var=word("`varlist'",`i')
        loca rnames="`rnames'"+" "+"`var':diff `var':t `var':p"
    }
    mat rownames T=`rnames'                         // difference, t value, p value

    loca i=1
    foreach var in `varlist'    {
        loca j=1
        su `grpvar', meanonly
        forval f=`r(min)'/`r(max)'  {
            su `var', meanonly
            loca ydbhat=`r(mean)'           // y double hat
            su `var' if `grpvar'==`f', meanonly
            loca diff=`ydbhat'-`r(mean)'    // difference

            qui ttest `var'=`ydbhat' if `grpvar'==`f'   // one-sample ttest
            mat T[`i',`j']=`diff'
            mat T[`i'+1,`j']=`r(t)'
            mat T[`i'+2,`j']=`r(p)'
            loca ++j
        }
        loca i=`i'+3
    }

mat list T, f(%8.3f)
```

Now I am not sure if 15 columns would be too wide. If so, change the display format or even just use `putexcel` to export the matrix into a spreadsheet.

**Edited**: Fixed the `forval i=0/1` in the loops to a more generally applicable form. Also other minor editing.

Comment: That is fantastic! Thanks so much! I had to go in and change the `forval f=0/1` to `forval f=1/15` to fit my group variable, but other than deleting the first line and inserting the variable names it worked great!

Comment: Great. And thanks for pointing out the issue. I updated that line to make it more generally applicable.

Comment: Helpful code. Note that if all you want are some or all of mean, minimum and maximum you should specify `meanonly` option of `summarize`. See http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=st0135

Comment: @NickCox Thanks for the tip! Do you happen to know which is more efficient: `tab x` or `summarize x, meanonly`?

Comment: Efficiency is not the name of the question here, as they do different things.

Comment: @NickCox Great suggestion. On a related matter, I summarized and extracted the same `r(min)' and `r(max)' twice in the code while I could've stored them as new macros the first time. Any reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: Difficult to answer that briefly. `forval` won't evaluate e.g. `r(min)` for you so you need to pass the local macro persona.

Comment: Not evaluating the argument is a good point. I guess need to reformulate the question more generally. It's just one of the minor debates I often have when coding.

Answer (score 0):

Edited the code a bit - can't post markdown in the comments, so I made it a new answer. This version does a two-sample t-test and also displays the cluster mean for each variable.

```
local varlist var1 var2 var3                   // put varlist here
local grpvar _clus_1                           // put grouping variable here
local n_var=wordcount("`varlist'")
qui summ `grpvar', meanonly
local n_grp=`r(max)'

mat T=J(`n_var'*4,`n_grp',.)                   // (# of vars*4,# of groups,.)

**colnames
    local cnames=""
    qui summ `grpvar', meanonly
    forval i=`r(min)'/`r(max)'  {              // assuming consecutive sequence
        local cnames="`cnames'"+" "+"`i'"
    }
    //di "`cnames'"
    mat colnames T=`cnames'                    // values of grouping variable

**rownames
    local rnames=""
    forval  i=1/`n_var' {
        local var=word("`varlist'",`i')
        local rnames="`rnames'"+" "+"`var':mean `var':diff `var':t-stat `var':p-value"
    }
    mat rownames T=`rnames'                    // mean, difference, t value, p value

    local i=1
    foreach var in `varlist'    {
        local j=1
        qui summ `grpvar'
        forval f=`r(min)'/`r(max)'   {
            qui summ `var'
            local varmean=`r(mean)'
            local varn = `r(N)'
            local varsd = `r(sd)'
            qui summ `var' if `grpvar'==`f'
            local clusmean = `r(mean)'
            local clusn = `r(N)'
            local clussd = `r(sd)'
            local diff=`clusmean'-`varmean'    // difference

    **two-sample t-test
            qui ttesti `varn' `varmean' `varsd' `clusn' `clusmean' `clussd' 

            mat T[`i',`j']=`clusmean'
            mat T[`i'+1,`j']=`diff'
            mat T[`i'+2,`j']=`r(t)'
            mat T[`i'+3,`j']=`r(p)'
            local ++j
        }
        local i=`i'+4
    }

mat list T, f(%8.3f)
```

Comment: Nice. Just one thing: I think `quiet` is redundant for `summarize var, meanonly`. As Nick's article (and the help file) suggests, `meanonly` automatically suppresses the terminal output.