# Stata putexcel summary statistics by group to MS Excel

Tags: excel, stata

I'm trying to get the Stata command `putexcel` to give me summary statistics for a continuous variable, grouped by a categorical variable, one after another, in the same worksheet. This should be repeated/looped through a number of years, where each year has its own sheet.

This poses two problems:

1. using `bysort` doesn't record all the groups (well maybe it does but I don't understand how to retrieve them), so it seems I have to use an if-condition for each level. Therefore, the problems becomes that:
2. There are a 150 categories (groups) in my categorical variable, all semi-random 4-digit numbers. So ideally, the solution would automatically detect the number of levels in the group-variabel instead of me writing in hand the 150 different categories for each if-statement.

Here is an example dataset:

```
clear
input ///
id income1996 income1997 employcode1996 employcode1997
1 500 400 3300 5000
2 500 300 5000 5000
3 900 1050 8830 8220
4 1000 1200 8220 3300
5 600 900 5000 8220
6 200 100 8220 5000
7 700 100 3300 3300
8 1000 100 5000 5000
end
```

And here is my not very good try to resolve the problem. I know the local variables are just as (in)efficient as just writing it in hand, but it was my best shot.

```
forval x=1996/1997 {
    local y=2
    local z=`y'+1
    local w=`y'+2   
    summarize income`x' if employcode`x'==3300
    putexcel A1=rnames A`z'=rscalars  using "C:\Users\emilbebri\Downloads\tmp\results.xlsx", sheet(year`x') modify colwise
    summarize income`x' if employcode`x'==5000 
    putexcel A`z'=rscalars  using "C:\Users\emilbebri\Downloads\tmp\results.xlsx", sheet(year`x') modify colwise
    summarize income`x' if employcode`x'==8220 
    putexcel A`w'=rscalars  using "C:\Users\emilbebri\Downloads\tmp\results.xlsx", sheet(year`x') modify colwise  
}
```

Would appreciate an answer greatly, and so would my rmi-strained righthand! 
[This guy seems to be on to something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24915409/create-comparison-of-means-table-with-multiple-variables-by-multiple-groups-comp/24920199#24920199), however, the actual content is too far off and I am at loss as how I would transfer that knowledge to my similar-but-kind-of-different problem.

Update: here is Robertos answer, but modified so that the output becomes more compact, like this: (the reason why the last row doesn't have mean and SD is because the example data has only one observation in that category)

[image]

and here is the code to produce it.

```
forvalues x = 1996/1997 {

    local xlsrow = 2

    quietly levelsof employcode`x', local(ecodes)
    foreach ecode of local ecodes {

        // show on screen
        quietly display "Year `x', code `ecode'"
        quietly summarize income`x' if employcode`x' == `ecode'
        quietly display ""

        // save to MS Excel
        putexcel A`xlsrow'=("Code `ecode'") B`xlsrow'=rscalars ///
            A1=("discokode") B1=rnames  ///
            using "C:\Users\emilbebri\Downloads\tmp\results11.xlsx", ///
            sheet(`x') modify colwise

        // update MS Excel row
        local xlsrow = `xlsrow' + 1

    }

}
```

Comment: Check `help levelsof`. Furthermore, consider working in _long_ form, rather than _wide_. Most analysis is easier this way. See `help reshape`.

Comment: Thank you, except I can't quite get it to work. I made an update to my post, inspired by this guy, but it isn't working, and I can't quite wrap my head around why: http://www.andrewdyck.com/using-levelsof-to-future-proof-a-loop-through-factorial-variables-in-stata/

Comment: You create `local employcode1996_tmp`, but never use it.

Comment: There is no such thing as "local variables" in Stata. It's either a "variable" or a "local (macro)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your updated code you are missing `{}` for the `forvalues` loop. Also, you don't make use of the `local employcode_tmp`, and that seems to be what you aim for.

Fixing the syntax errors I mention and deleting your second `quietly` should give you some output. However, your loop gives repeated results (five for each employment code). I'm not sure that's intentional.

A complete working example, with my interpretation of what you want, is

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
id income1996 income1997 employcode1996 employcode1997
1 500 400 3300 5000
2 500 300 5000 5000
3 900 1050 8830 8220
4 1000 1200 8220 3300
5 600 900 5000 8220
6 200 100 8220 5000
7 700 100 3300 3300
8 1000 100 5000 5000
end

*----- what you want -----

forvalues x = 1996/1997 {

    local xlsrow = 1

    quietly levelsof employcode`x', local(ecodes)
    foreach ecode of local ecodes {

        // show on screen
        display "Year `x', code `ecode'"
        summarize income`x' if employcode`x' == `ecode'
        display ""

        // save to MS Excel
        putexcel A`xlsrow'=("Code `ecode'") A`=`xlsrow'+1'=rscalars ///
            using "D:/Datos/rferrer/Desktop/test.xlsx", ///
            sheet(`x') modify colwise

        // update MS Excel row
        local xlsrow = `xlsrow' + 3

    }

}
```

The result:

[image]

Check also `help statsby`.

Comment: That worked magic. I learned a lot from seeing how you did it, so thank you. I made a more compact output based on your code, that I've added to my original question.